# Preserving xattr on download

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to store some metadata in a .txt file using xattr on a website, then download it. If I use PHP's xattr_set on the temporary file when running the website locally, both xattr_list in PHP and python-xattr on the command line show me the attributes I set. However, when I download the file using readfile, the attributes no longer show up. Is there any way to  preserve these attributes on download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly. HTTP has no way of specifying filesystem extended attributes, so you will need to package them in an appropriate archive format that allows specifying them in the metadata, e.g. GNU tar with `--xattrs`.

Comment: Well that's annoying. Thank you for the quick response!